# Limitar la canidad de letras por linea para imprimir

Tags: c#, windows-forms, imprimir, impresión

Estoy haciendo un ticket de factura y necesito limitar la cantidad de letras que se escriben por linea a 35 máximo, esto porque es para un ticket de 80mm en primera instancia, luego vendrán los de pagina completa pero si logro hacerlo con los pequeños primero creo que podre controlar las de pagina completa. El código que uso para imprimir el ticket es este:

```
    private PrintDocument Doc = new PrintDocument();
    private PrintPreviewDialog Ver  = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    public List<Cabecera> ListaCabe = new List<Cabecera>();
    public List<Cliente> ListaCli  = new List<Cliente>();
    public List<Cuerpo>   ListaProd = new List<Cuerpo>();
    public List<Totales>  ListTotal = new List<Totales>();

    public void Imprimir(Impresion p) 
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings;
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ticket);
            doc.Print();
        }
    }
    public void ticket(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int posX, posY;
        Font Letra = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular);

        StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        format1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        format1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        StringFormat format2 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        format2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        format2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

        try
        {
            //Cabecera
            posX = 10;
            posY = 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].CIA, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].Dir, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].Ciu, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].Tel, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("RNC: " + ListaCabe[0].RNC, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].Fec, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            //NO. y tipo de factura
            posX = 15;
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].NoVTA, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX += 50;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaCabe[0].TipoVTA, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 10;
            posX = 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            //Clientes
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("CLIENTE  : " + ListaCli[0].CodCLi, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("NOMBRE   : " + ListaCli[0].NomCLi, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("CEDULA   : " + ListaCli[0].TaxCLi, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TELEFONO : " + ListaCli[0].TelCli, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("DIRECCION: " + ListaCli[0].DirCli, Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);//Necesito limitar aqui
            posX = 10;
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            //Encabezado de articulos
            posX = 15;
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("ARTICULO", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX += 70;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("CANTIDAD", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX += 75;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("PRECIO", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX += 75;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TOTAL", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX = 10;
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posY += 15;
            //Articulos
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaProd.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaProd[i].DetArt, Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 350, 20));//Necesito limitar aqui
                posY += 15;
                posX = 10;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(ListaProd[i].CodArt, Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 70, 20), format1);
                posX += 70;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListaProd[i].CntArt +" "+ ListaProd[i].UMArt), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 70, 20), format1);
                posX += 70;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListaProd[i].PreArt), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 70, 20), format1);
                posX += 70;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListaProd[i].TotArt), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 70, 20), format1);
                posX = 10;
                posY += 15;
            }
            posX = 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            //Totales
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TOTAL BRUTO-------------->", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX = 175;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListTotal[0].TtlBru), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 100, 20), format2);
            posX = 10;
            posY += 15;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("IMPUESTO----------------->", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX = 175;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListTotal[0].ImpFac), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 100, 20), format2);
            posX = 10;
            posY += 15;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TOTAL-------------------->", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            posX = 175;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(ListTotal[0].TtlNet), Letra, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(posX, posY, 100, 20), format2);
            posX = 10;
            posY += 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------", Letra, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
            ListaProd.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception){throw;}
    }
```

Como notaran, de donde saco los datos es de varias listas e imprimo todo a lo largo, pero necesito que se me limite a 35 como dije antes y lo que reste que salte a la otra linea, necesito que lo haga en **la cabecera, los artículos y el ciertos datos del cliente** que por lo general serán los que tiendan a pasarse de largo.